# Primefaces datatable filter() function not working with one managed class but working with another

Tags: java, jsf, filter, datatable, primefaces

[Here is before i add any filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNkKg.png)

[Here after i add a search term](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlweu.png)

Right after when i delete the search term the datatable stays like that , empty.

On the other hand , i have a perfectly working datatable with search function for another manager class, so i dont really understand the problem.

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "laboratorio")
    @SessionScoped
    public class Laboratorio implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1094801825228386322L;
        private LaboratorioDAO ldao;
        private Integer id;
        private String msg;
    
        private String tipoSangre;
    
        private List<Donantevalidar> users;
        private List<Donantevalidar> usersFiltrados;
    
        public Integer getId() {
    
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Integer pwd) {
            this.id = pwd;
        }
    
        public List<Donantevalidar> getUsers() {
            return users;
        }
    
        public void setListavalidar(List<Donantevalidar> users) {
            this.users = users;
        }
    
        public void setUsersFiltrados(List<Donantevalidar> users) {
            this.usersFiltrados = users;
        }
    
        public List<Donantevalidar> getUsersFiltrados() {
            return usersFiltrados;
        }
    
        public String getTipoSangre() {
            return tipoSangre;
        }
    
        public void setTipoSangre(String pwd) {
            this.tipoSangre = pwd;
        }

        public void listaSangre() {
            LaboratorioImpl ldao2 = new LaboratorioImpl();
            setListavalidar(ldao2.generarTabla());
    
        }
    
    }
```

Here is my html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Borrar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="borrar.css"></link>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/22e24bcbd3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </h:head>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="screen">
            <div class="screen__content">
                <h:body onload="#{laboratorio.listaSangre()}">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h:form>
                            <div class="box2">
                                <div class="login__field" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 50px">
                                    <br></br>
                                    <h1> 
                                        Validar muestras</h1>

                                </div>
                                <div class="login__field" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <br></br>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <h2> 
                                        Nombre de usuario</h2>


                                    <p:inputText  class="login__input" id="username" value="#{laboratorio.id}"    ></p:inputText >
                                    <div class="errorMensaje" style="position: absolute; top:200px; z-index: 99999">
                                        <p:messages for="MessageId" showDetail="true"  closable="true"></p:messages>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="login__field2">
                                    <h:commandLink action="#{login.logout}" value="Logout" styleClass="button2 login__submit2">
                                        <i class="button__icon fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <br /><br />

                            <br /><br />

                            <br /><br />

                            <h:message for="username"></h:message>
                            <br /><br />


                            <div class="errorMensaje" style="position: absolute; top:-5px;">
                                <p:messages for="MessageId" showDetail="true"  closable="true"></p:messages>
                            </div>
                            <div class="login__field">
                                <p:commandLink class="button login__submit"  value="Borrar" type="button" styleClass="button login__submit" style="text-decoration:none;color: #4C489D;;" onclick="PF('deleteDlg').show()">
                                    <i class="button__icon fas fa-user-slash "></i>
                                </p:commandLink>

                                <h:commandLink class="button login__submit" action="#{laboratorio.listaSangre()}" value="Actualizar tabla" styleClass="button login__submit">
                                    <i class="button__icon fas fa-sync"></i>
                                </h:commandLink>

                                <p:commandLink class="button login__submit"  value="Anyadir" type="button" styleClass="button login__submit" style="text-decoration:none;color: #4C489D;;" onclick="PF('validarDlg').show()">
                                    <i class="button__icon fas fa-user-slash "></i>
                                </p:commandLink>

                            </div>


                        </h:form>

                    </div>  <h:form>
                        <div class="tabla">

                            <p:dataTable  value="#{laboratorio.users}" var="var" lazy="true" filteredValue="#{laboratorio.usersFiltrados}" widgetVar="customersTable" emptyMessage="No hay coincidencias" paginator="true"
                                          paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                          currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords} records"
                                          rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,{ShowAll|'All'}" style="table-layout: auto;">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Busqueda global:" />
                                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('customersTable').filter()" style="width:150px" />
                                    <p:separator />

                                </f:facet>

                                <p:column filterBy="#{var.tipo}" headerText="Tipo de sangre"    filterMatchMode="contains">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{var.tipo}" />
                                </p:column>




                            </p:dataTable>




                        </div>
                    </h:form>

                </h:body>
            </div>
            <div class="screen__background"> <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape4"></span>
                <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape3"></span>      
                <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape2"></span>
                <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape1"></span></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

My working datatable is basically the same but with 4 columns and of other object class, have tried cleaning my cache , rebuilding project , etc. The only other thing that could be wrong is that some of the data retrieved from the database are "utfmb4" - charset and collation "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci" dont know if this could cause it.
(EDIT) Im using primefaces 10.0.0

Answer (score -1):

Solved this problem , i was using THE WRONG FREKING IMPORTS NO WONDER IT DIDNT WORK